# Determining the Windows 10 version

Tags: windows-10, version

The following [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/13443/windows-which-operating-system) describes how to determine the Windows 10 version of a computer.

However, it only lets you find out the build number, it doesn't tell you whether it's running the Creator's Update or Anniversary Update, ect. How can you figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has a complete list of the [Windows 10 Version History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history):

```
| Version | Release Name         | Release Date |
|---------|----------------------|--------------|
| 1507    | Initial Release      | 2015-07-29   |
| 1511    | November Update      | 2015-11-10   |
| 1607    | Anniversary Update   | 2016-08-02   |
| 1703    | Creators Update      | 2017-04-05   |
| 1709    | Fall Creators Update | 2017-10-17   |
| 1803    | April 2018 Update    | 2018-04-30   |
| 1809    | October 2018 Update  | 2018-11-13   |
| 1903    | May 2019 Update      | 2019-05-21   |
| 1909    | November 2019 Update | 2019-11-12   |
| 2004    | May 2020 Update      | 2020-05-27   |
```

To find out which version of Windows your PC is running:

- Press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Type `winver`
- Select OK

[image: About Windows]

Comment: That's nice as it will be updated if new versions come out!

Comment: fall creators update will be 1709, next 1803, 1809

Answer (score 1):

The following [link](https://www.cnet.com/au/how-to/how-to-tell-if-your-pc-is-running-windows-10-creators-update/) lists the Anniversary Update as Version 1607 and the Creators Update as Version 1703. If your version number is that or higher, then you are running that version.